# SQL Conversion Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I really need a second pair of eyes on this... I have a Stored Procedure with a variable:

```
DECLARE @date_period_end int 

IF @date_period_end = '' or @date_period_end is null  
BEGIN 
    SET @date_period_end = 'DATEDIFF(dd, ''1/1/1753'', CONVERT(datetime,getdate())) + 639906 ' 
END
```

Here is the error SQL returning when I execute:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DATEDIFF(dd, '1/1/1753', CONVERT(datetime,getdate())) + 639906 ' to data type int.

I'm pretty certain I'm missing or have added an incorrect amount of quotes somewhere.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all... you all had the same answer.  I did encase the entire variable in quotes... didn't need to do that.  You're all awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a quote around
DATEDIFF(dd, '1/1/1753', CONVERT(datetime,getdate())) + 639906

remove the quotes and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You've got quotes around your `DATEDIFF` function, making it a string literal, and I'm pretty sure that's not what you intended. Try this:

```
DECLARE @date_period_end int 

IF @date_period_end = '' or @date_period_end is null  
BEGIN 
    SET @date_period_end = DATEDIFF(dd, '1/1/1753', CONVERT(datetime,getdate())) + 639906
END
```

---

Side note: I'm not sure why you're comparing an integer with the empty string (`@date_period_end = ''`) and what you expect it will do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BEGIN
   SET @date_period_end = DATEDIFF(dd, '1/1/1753', CONVERT(datetime,getdate())) + 639906  
END
```

There were incorrect quotes around DATEDIFF() and double quotes around the dummy date

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @date_period_end int

IF @date_period_end = '' or @date_period_end is null  
BEGIN 
SET @date_period_end = DATEDIFF(dd,'1/1/1753',CONVERT(datetime,getdate())) + 639906
END
```

you can also see the value of this variable  using below statement along with the above code:

```
Print @date_period_end
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the extra quotes did the trick - and I've simplified your IF check using ISNULL

```
DECLARE @date_period_end int 

IF ISNULL(@date_period_end,'') = '' 
BEGIN 
    SET @date_period_end = DATEDIFF(dd, '1/1/1753', CONVERT(datetime,getdate())) + 639906 
END
```